# RealmSwift saving after convenience init

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, savechanges

I'm retrieving user information from api, create a realm object and then I want to save it in realm.
The problem is that it doesn't update the user. I have a Manager class to deal with realm. Inside this class I create my Realm variable that I'm using every time I need to read or write:

```
let myrealm = try! Realm()
```

then inside a function I do:

```
let rmUser = RMUser(id:1, code:"ewi39", ...) //init
//here, for example, rmUser.code = "ewi39"
try! myrealm.write {
    myrealm.add(rmUser, update:true)
}
//here rmUser.code = "" , which was the value of the already stored user.
```

Any idea why?
I have several convenience init in the RMUser, the one I'm using here is like:

```
convenience init(id:Int, code:String, ...) {
    self.init()
    self.id = id
    self.code = code
    ...
}
```

Strange enough (to me)is that if I don't call the initializer, but I just assign variables "manually", it works properly:

```
let rmUser = RMUser()
rmUser.id = id
rmUser.code = code
//here, for example, rmUser.code = "ewi39"
try myrealm.write {
    myrealm.add(rmUser, update:true)
}
//here rmUser.code is "ewi39" as should be
```

Comment: Is your second example also dispatched to the main thread asynchronously? How/where are you checking whether the write transaction succeeded or not? Btw if you want to keep a global reference to your `Realm` (which I really wouldn't advise doing), you should create a dedicated `DispatchQueue` and convenience methods for accessing the global `Realm` reference from that queue synchronously/asynchronously rather than always accessing it in an async manner from the main thread.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks, I've edited the question, removed the async, as it wasn't that thing causing the issue, I also added try! as my code was a sort of example, I actually catch the error, but there is no error while writing. Furthermore, myrealm wasn't global, is a variable of the Manager class.